# How to determine method names and parameters in wsdl web service

Tags: parameters, wsdl, ksoap2

I have few problems with Web Services and KSoap library. I searched this topic before asking but couldn't find anything.

Here is the question : I have an url like http://www.anyting.com/bulkService.wsdl but i haven't got any documentation about it. Can I determine **METHOD NAME** and **NAMESPACE** parameters just examining wsdl file. 
Example  : *http://www.webservicex.net/isbn.asmx?WSDL*

If it is possible, where can i found method parameters for sending request.

I'm working on Android Project so I'm using KSoap2, that what i need METHOD NAME and NAMESPACE.

Little question : Is *myservice.wsdl*  url same *myservice.asmx?WSDL*

Thanks for your support..

**Edit #1 :** I spend a lot of time and i got the right parameters like that :

- **METHOD_NAME :** Web service may have multiple methods. If you didn't find documents about your web service, you can search method names in wsdl. If your web service extension is .asmx then your wsdl like ../services/service.asmx?wsdl. Open wsdl file and search "operation name", this parameters are your Methods. Choose what if you want to use.
- **NAMESPACE :** Open your wsdl and search "targetNamespace". This parameter is your NAMESPACE parameter.
- **SOAP_ACTION :** This parameter is composed of Method Name and Namespace. Use it like that String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;

  - **URL :** Find "service" element in wsdl. This element contains "wsdlsoap:address location =" This address is your web service's URL.

Comment: Well it took me a while. I use this site to generate SOAP request from [http://www.soapclient.com/SoapMsg.html](http://www.soapclient.com/SoapMsg.html) site (scroll down). And [http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl](http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?wsdl) for WSDL file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can find it. Go [here](http://www.webservicex.net/isbn.asmx) and click on method which parameters you want to see. in this example

GetISBNInformation is the method click on it and you will get SOAP_ACTION and parameters. everything you need to know to send request using KSOAP. Cheers.

Comment: The above link shows unavailable
Service Unavailable

Comment: The link is being used one from the question, so it's dead now. but you can see the url and try to do same with your webservice url and see if it works?

Comment: WebServiceX.net has removed ALL of their SOAP examples, many people consider SOAP legacy and abandoned.  For example MS even explicitly announced it will not be added to .NET Core

Answer (score 12):

this should help out (php):

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://my_exposed_url?wsdl");
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());    
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```