# Is it correct to use ?wsdl on methods of webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

It is possible to get webservice description by checking ?wsdl link of a service.

For example:

```
somewebsite.com/myservice.svc?wsdl
```

Is it possible to get a discription of a method by going to wsdl link of a method?

for example:

```
somewebsite.com/myservice.svc/Method?wsdl
```

Comment: it's possible duplicate. see this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295181/how-to-determine-method-names-and-parameters-in-wsdl-web-service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine method names and parameters in wsdl web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295181/how-to-determine-method-names-and-parameters-in-wsdl-web-service)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out adding ?wsdl to the end of .svc method won't give XML